# Jenkins archiveArtifacts generates 'not found' error

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, artifacts

I have very simple pipeline, like this:

```
pipeline {
    agent any
    stages {
        stage('Build Automation') {
            steps {
                sh '''
                echo "BUILD NUMBER: ${BUILD_NUMBER}"
                cd myproject
                mvn clean package 
                '''
            }
        }
        stage('Prepare artifacts') {
            steps {
                sh '''
                cd myproject/target
                ls
                archiveArtifacts 'myproject/target/*' 
                '''
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The `Build Automation` step finishes successfully but I'm always getting error form the `archiveArtifacts':

```
[myproject-automation_master-FALMJHZX7ZH5GMLQBBOYFJQRFPX4WIHQXBH2YXEQDL4TDAMTRYTQ] Running shell script
+ cd myproject/target
+ ls
classes
generated-sources
generated-test-sources
myapp
myapp.war
maven-archiver
maven-status
test-classes
+ archiveArtifacts myproject/target/*
/var/jenkins_home/workspace/myproject-automation_master-FALMJHZX7ZH5GMLQBBOYFJQRFPX4WIHQXBH2YXEQDL4TDAMTRYTQ@tmp/durable-6a43d2f0/script.sh: 5: /var/jenkins_home/workspacemyproject-automation_master-FALMJHZX7ZH5GMLQBBOYFJQRFPX4WIHQXBH2YXEQDL4TDAMTRYTQ@tmp/durable-6a43d2f0/script.sh: archiveArtifacts: not found
```

I've added `ls` to see if there are any files in the `target` folder, so they are there, but the archiveArtifacts always returns not found. I've tried various patterns like `*.war`, `**/target/*.war` , but no luck.

What might be wrong?

Comment: Instead of using `cd "myproject/target"`, you can consider  `dir('myproject/target')` if you want archiveArtifacts to run in that directory.

For eg., dir('new_directory') {steps}

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to remove the archiveArtifacts step from the sh step. The way it is right now it is being run as part of the shell script and interpreted as a command.

```
        steps {
            sh '''
                cd myproject/target
                ls
            '''
            archiveArtifacts 'myproject/target/*' 
        }
```

The above should work.

Comment: Thanks a lot! It worked. My bad, this happens when you're doing something for the 1st time, not understanding yet all the details.